# How to create a multisetup with selection ,deployment project in .net?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am having multiple setup projects which are to be installed .I am trying to create a single setup project which includes all the setup projects and user have a choice to install only the selected setup project.My imagined prototype is similar to visual studio installer , which gives a choice to install particular components.This what i wanted... I am googling to find a answer regarding this ,starting with stackoverflow where i get all my questions cleared .I am anticipating some kind possibility for my  question.

Thanks in advance,